# How to copy Windows system files using linux?

Tags: windows-7, linux, ntfs, ntfs-3g

I want to migrate my Windows 7 to an SSD. The SSD is 80G, and the system is installed on a 500G partition, most of which is used. So, I can't just clone the partition.

I have an Ubuntu LiveCD, and I want to copy the system files using that, then run Windows Restore from the installation disk to make the SSD bootable.

I'm concerned about copying two things: file permissions and NTFS symlinks. Does the NTFS driver in Linux handle them correctly, so I can just copy the files over? Or should I use a special utility for that?

UPD: 'just copying files' chokes on some 'special file' in `Windows\SysWoW64`. Figures.

Comment: If you could do this, then nothing would be stopping you from giving away the SSD to somebody else. So, I'm pretty sure that some license somewhere makes this illegal. Feel free to try, though.

Answer (score 0):

I'm surprised, but Paragon Migrate to SSD (I'm not affiliated, so google it) did the job perfectly.

It lets you choose which directories to copy, and even copies boot config.

If there are any disadvantages, then it's the price ($20 for a one-shot operation).